# Why affecting a localStorage string value to a css parameter in a marker never changes in the DOM inspector?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm using ReactJS, and I want to have a dark and light mode, which change the entire website. (images, colors...)
My button to switch between themes is in my navbar, which is a component from my app, but I want to change my entire app.

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap"
import { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";


import '../fonts/AdigianaUI.ttf'
import Logo from "../img/logo.png";
import DarkMoon from "../img/dark_moon.png";
import Sun from "../img/sun.png";
import '../sass/App.scss';
import '../css/navbar.css';

class Navigation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loggedIn: false,
            userData: {}
        }
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("theme"));
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        if (user) {
            this.setState({
                loggedIn: true,
                userData: user
            })
        }
    }
    render() {
        const switchTheme = () => {
            var theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
            console.log("before", theme);
  
            if (theme === "light") {
                localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
                theme = "dark";
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
                theme = "light";
            }
            console.log("var", theme, "local", localStorage.getItem("theme"))

        }
        return (
            <>
                <Row>
                    <Navbar id="nav" bg="light" expand="lg">
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Col className="vert left" lg={4}>
                                <Link to="/"><img src={Logo} height="50" className="" alt="logo" /></Link>

                                <button onClick={() => switchTheme()} className="toggle-theme img-theme"><img src={Sun} height="30" className="" alt="logo" /></button>
                            </Col>

                            <Col className="mid" lg={4}>
                                <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/events">Événements</Link>
                                <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/articles">Articles</Link>
                                <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/otakulture">Otakulture</Link>
                            </Col>

                            <Col className="right" lg={4}>
                                {this.state.loggedIn ?
                                    <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/account">{this.state.userData.username}</Link>
                                    :
                                    <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/sign">Se connecter</Link>
                                }
                            </Col>

                        </Navbar.Collapse>

                    </Navbar>
                </Row>
            </>
        );
    }
} export default Navigation
```

I can't pull informations from a child component to the main app to change the entire scss and image files.
So I tried to use the localstorage, to store the theme, when clicking on the button, and switching between 2 strings, which I pull to my **data-theme** parameter, which is a string.

I made a verifier, if in the local storage my theme switch well :
print

```
var light local light
```

when switching to light mode checking the storaged value and the value from the script
and vice versa print

```
before light
var dark local dark
```

when switching to dark

Here is my App component with the data-theme parameter.

```
import React, { Component, createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Routes
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap"
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import './sass/App.scss';

import Navigation from "./components/Navigation.jsx";
import Acceuil from "./pages/Acceuil.jsx";
import Events from "./pages/Events.jsx";
import Articles from "./pages/Articles.jsx";
import Otakulture from "./pages/Otakulture.jsx";
import Account from "./pages/Account.jsx";
import Sign from "./pages/Sign.jsx";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            theme: "",
            loggedIn: false,
            userData: {}
        }
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        if (user) {
            this.setState({
                loggedIn: true,
                userData: user
            })
        }
    }



    render() {
        const actualTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");  // theme is a string
        return (
            <>
                <div id="app" className="app" data-theme={actualTheme} //this parameter expect a string
                    <Router>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route exact path="/" element={<Acceuil  />} />
                            <Route exact path="/events" element={<Events  />} />
                            <Route exact path="/articles" element={<Articles  />} />
                            <Route exact path="/otakulture" element={<Otakulture  />} />
                            <Route exact path="/sign" element={<Sign  />} />
                            <Route exact path="/account" element={<Account  />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </Router>
                    <Row>
                        <Navbar id="nav" bg="light" expand="lg">
                            {/* <Container> */}
                            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">

                                <Col className="vert left" lg={4}>
                                    {/* <Link to="/"><img src={Logo} height="50" className="" alt="logo" /></Link> */}
                                    {/* <ThemeButton /> */}
                                    {/* <button onClick={() => switchTheme()} className="toggle-theme img-theme"><img src={Sun} height="30" className="" alt="logo" /></button> */}
                                </Col>

                                <Col className="mid" lg={4}>
                                    {/* <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/events">Événements</Link> */}
                                    {/* <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/articles">Articles</Link> */}
                                    {/* <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/otakulture">Otakulture</Link> */}
                                </Col>

                                <Col className="right" lg={4}>
                                    {/* {this.state.loggedIn ?
                                        <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/account">{this.state.userData.username}</Link>
                                        :
                                        <Link className="align-items-center" id="navlink" to="/sign">Se connecter</Link>
                                    } */}
                                </Col>

                            </Navbar.Collapse>

                        </Navbar>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my SCSS targetting the element which has the **data-theme** parameter (my div which contains my app)

```
  [data-theme="dark"] {
    transition: all .7s;
      --background: black;
      --background-secondary: var(--yellow1);
      --text-primary: white;
      --text-secondary: black;
      --background-image-main: url('../img/dark_background_logo.png');
      --background-image-twitch: url('../img/Background-twitch-dark.png');
      --background-linear: black;
      
      
      
    }
    [data-theme="light"] {
        transition: all .7s;
        --background: white;
        --background-secondary: var(--yellow1);
        --text-primary: black;
        --text-secondary: white;
        --background-image-main: url('../img/light_background_logo.png');
        --background-image-twitch: url('../img/Background-twitch-light.png');
        --background-linear-: linear-gradient(var(--yellow1), var(--yellow3), white);

    }
```

When I check the parameter in the DOM, the data-theme in the div class never change, but my locaclStorage value which I give to the data-theme parameter changes well.

And I know the DOM parameter can be changed by this data-theme when inspecting it.

If someone knows how to make it work, please tell me !
I know that I can do it using Redux, but just to know If it's possible to avoid Redux in this case, cause it's a little bit of work to implement it

Thank you dor reading it !

Comment: Instead of using local storage, try storing that value in context hook. And then you can get the data regarding theme in anyother component in app your app tree. Also advantage of doing that would be, react will detect that change of state in your application and will render appropriately according to the theme settings. On top of it you can write the value to localstorage and check if it’s available on app load, to ensure when user comes back after closing a page, he gets his settings.

Comment: Long story short, reading the issue, it looks to me that you are updating local storage with the data about your theme, but react doesn’t knows “and it will not re render your app until and  unless there’s an update on some state in app’s context ”.